# Is the Taskbar Visible?

Tags: delphi, taskbar, visible

I need to know if the Taskbar is Assigned but the "Auto Hide Taskbar" has been checked and the Taskbar is temporarily hidden. I have a Function the returns the Height of the Taskbar if it has been assigned or zero if not.

But, if the Windows "Auto Hide" option has been set, the Function still returns the height for the Taskbar, although it is not visible until the cursor moves to the bottom edge of the screen.

When I set
Image.Height:=Screen.Height-MyTaskbarHeight
it sets the image height as if the task bar was visible all of the time.

In pseudo-code, what I need is

```
if Taskbar.Assigned then
if Taskbar.AutoHide.Checked then // Assume it is hidden
    Image.Height:=Screen.Height else
    Image.Height:=Screen.Height-MyTaskbarHeight;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you compare the work area to the desktop area? But I cannot begin to imagine why you would want to know this info in the first place.

Comment: David's second remark is almost an answer in its own right, because if you need this information, you are most likely doing something bad.

Comment: The first sentence in my comment is drivel though!

Comment: Doing something bad? What inane drivel. Because your tiny minds cannot think of creative applications, you assume I must be doing something bad. DUH!

Comment: Creative approach, ahahaha, nice try, boy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TAppBarData is defined in ShellAPI.

```
var
  ABData : TAppBarData;
  State: Cardinal;
begin
  ABData.cbSize := sizeof(ABData);
  State := SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, ABData);
  Result := (State and ABS_AUTOHIDE) = ABS_AUTOHIDE;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks to you too Arjen. Exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

```
Uses
  ShellApi;

function  IsTaskbarAutoHideOn : Boolean;
Var
 ABData : TAppBarData;
begin
  ABData.cbSize := SizeOf(ABData);
  Result:= (SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, ABData) and ABS_AUTOHIDE)<>0;
end;


function GetTaskBarRect(var ARect: TRect): Integer;
var
    ABData: TAppBarData;
begin
  ABData.cbSize := SizeOf(ABData);
  if SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ABData) <> 0 then
  Result := ABData.uEdge;
  ARect  := ABData.rc;
end;
```

Comment: +1 thanks to the link and the `<>0` test which I find slightly more natural.

Comment: Thanks RRUZ I will check that link also, but the code looks good.